# Close/Hide SoftinputKeyboard in kotlin

Tags: android, keyboard, kotlin

I have one button and edittext. I want to close my soft keyboard when user complete input in edittext and press button.

Or any guide or reference link for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I slightly modify response of @Serj Ardovic

```
private fun hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    view?.apply {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

as its really works for my requirement

Answer (score 4):

Call this function to hide the system keyboard:

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend all `EditText` with new function, which will be hide soft keyboard always when focus for `EditText` is lost. If you want hide keyboard, when focus for some `EditText` is lost, just use this line of code for this `EditText`

```
editText.hideSoftKeyboardOnFocusLostEnabled(true)
```

In extension for `EditText` we just add or remove our own `OnFocusLostListener`

```
fun EditText.hideSoftKeyboardOnFocusLostEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
    val listener = if (enabled)
        OnFocusLostListener()
    else
        null
    onFocusChangeListener = listener
}
```

Here is implementation of `OnFocusLostListener` which hides keyboard if focus for attached `View` is lost.

```
class OnFocusLostListener: View.OnFocusChangeListener {
    override fun onFocusChange(v: View, hasFocus: Boolean) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            val imm = v.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard(mActivity: Activity) {
        // Check if no view has focus:
        val view = mActivity.currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            val inputManager = mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }

    fun showKeyboard(yourEditText: EditText, activity: Activity) {
        try {
            val input = activity
                    .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            input.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()

        }
    }
```